# Agora.io DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY with generated RTC Token (php)

Tags: javascript, php, token, agora.io

I have a problem:
I get DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY in console trying to establish a connection.

2 Tokens which are generated by an Agora Console and rtcTokenBuilder are different, the second is longer, and using it occurs this error. With console Token is everything ok.

Token examples:
Console: 0068bedd2631cf24edea47479b64ad219ceIAAYXDdhxjKQyDWQEoqK0qEiAYo+dLSyd/YNAaflVD4PJO/ZQc0AAAAAEACMMKzfQDg1YAEAAQA/ODVg

rtcTokenBuilder:
0068bedd2631cf24edea47479b64ad219ceIAADpmWghbJIToZQMC9YrQjBhtFgpdZS4tIlOkXTjk+LKe/ZQc0h39v0IgCa0wUAjQY2YAQAAQA5tjRgAwA5tjRgAgA5tjRgBAA5tjRg

**rtcTokenBuilder** Code snippet:

```
$appID = "8*************************";
$appCertificate = "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++7";
$channelName = "Test Chamber";
$uid = 0;
$role = RtcTokenBuilder::RoleAttendee;
$expireTimeInSeconds = 300; // 5 min for test purposes
$currentTimestamp = (new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->getTimestamp();
$privilegeExpiredTs = $currentTimestamp + $expireTimeInSeconds;
$token = RtcTokenBuilder::buildTokenWithUid($appID, $appCertificate, $channelName, $uid, $role, $privilegeExpiredTs);
echo $token;
```

js file:

```
client.join(token, room, 0, (uid) => { // 0 -> uid
    let localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    });
    localStream.init(() => 
      .....

client.on("onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: tokenGenPath, // path to rtcTokenBuilder php generator  
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data){
           newToken = data;
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
    client.renewToken(newToken);
});
```

It says here, that I do not provide a Token prior connection: [Agora Docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/faq/token_error#120-dynamic-user-using-the-static-key)

P.S. I've noticed also, if I generate a Token in Agora console for the start and in case of expiration of this Token a new **valid** Token is generated from rtcTokenBuilder and connection/conversation continues.
[image]

Comment: @Hermes, I saw, that you have a lot of experience with WebRTC Technologies and especially in Agora things, may be you can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was at 2 places. First, I changed AJAX Call

From

```
client.on("onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire", function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: tokenGenPath, // path to rtcTokenBuilder php generator  
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data){
       newToken = data;
    },
    error: function(){
    }
 });
  client.renewToken(newToken);
});
```

To:

```
client.on("onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire", function(){
   $.post(tokenGenPath, function (token){
      client.renewToken(token);
    });
});
```

The second, I moved first Token generation out of the main function with client initialisation:

```
$.post(tokenGenPath, function (data){
   token = data;    
});

function runApp (room, client, token){
    client.join(token, room, 0, (uid) => { // 0 -> uid
       let localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
       audio: true,
       video: true
    });
    localStream.init(() => 
        .....
}
```

[image]